# How can I avoid using $conn in every single query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm just changed my code from **mysql** to **mysqli** and it seems to be best if:

How can i avoid of using `$conn` in every single queries or some mysqli's functions?

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "test", "", "world"); 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from user where id = '1'");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from company where name = 'marcus'");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "...");
mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, "my string");
```

How can i do this?

```
mysqli_query("select * from user where id = '1'");
mysqli_real_escape_string("my string");
```

Using of `$conn->query("...")` is not what i'm looking for because it doesn't have auto suggest from Dreamweaver.

Comment: + A big thumbs up for changing from MySQL to MySQLi :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only avoid using `$conn` in every single connection if you change your code to become object oriented (but this means using `$conn->query`).

I suggest maybe moving away from Dreamweaver (I'm sure a large amount of people will agree) and use something different like Sublime Text or another text editor. You can't then rely on auto-suggest but then you're learning as you have to remember what everything is.

If auto-suggest is what you like using however, then stick with Dreamweaver and unfortunately put up with having to keep including `$conn`.

I will add that most other text editors do include auto-suggest for variables, objects and more. I have mentioned Sublime Text but there are other paid for and free text editors like Coda and Notepad++.

Comment: Not relying on auto-complete means wasting valuable time remembering trivial stuff you shouldn't be concerned with. A proper IDE must be able to offer autocomplete, *especially* for objects.

Comment: I don't *rely* on auto-complete but yes most IDE's do come with some form of auto-complete. I just prefer to not use them as that's how I learn. That's how I learn best (typing it out rather than getting auto-complete to do it for me) but other people learn in different ways. :) @Duroth

Comment: thanks, I think this the best practice that i should to do :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't. If your principle reason is auto suggest on Dreamweaver then I recommend either:

- Using a OO shaped structure
- Using another IDE
- Learning your code so you don't need to rely on dreamweaver auto suggest
- Ignore DW.

Answer (score 1):

This will be against best practices, but you can define a new function using global variables.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "test", "", "world");

function sql_query($sql) {
    global $conn;
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}

sql_query("select * from user where id = '1'");
```

Comment: a genuinely interesting answer. not best practise but interesting, although it doesn't solve his issue as Dreamweaver will not recognise the local function and so will not offer the suggestions he's looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Put `$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "test", "", "world");` in a separate file, like `conn.php` and `include()` that in the top of all your pages you need to access MySQL.

Comment: But for every single query you'll still need to have `mysqli_query($conn...`

Comment: I don't think this answers his question, I think he wants to avoid using the variable in order to conform to Dreamweavers expectations.

Comment: Ah my bad, I didn't read throughfully. This would leverage some maintainance-issues in his/her code though.